# How to implement jQuery inputmask to @Html.TextBoxFor()

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-inputmask

I have an

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Expiration, new {@placeholder="MM/YY"})
```

that I'm trying to apply RobinHerbots jquery.inputmask (http://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) to so as the user types they would see something similar to

Starting: MM/YY

After First Character: 0M/YY

Second Character: 04/YY

and so on.

I've applied

```
$("#Expiration").inputmask({mask:"MM/YY",greedy:false});
```

However I get MM/YY in my text input without being able to click on it. Any assistance would be great.

Comment: I think inputmask mask should be "99/99" instead of "MM/YY". Can you try it?

Comment: Yup, this is where I was going with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mask attribute of InputMask is used to fill the input with a formatter.

The char used to say that a place will accept only numbers is "9"

So, mask = "99/99" will accept just numbers in 4 places. And the "/" char will mask its value.

In your case, if you want a mask like "MM/YY", and all of this chars should be numbers, the correct mask is "99/99"